jertech 348 keyboard backlight in ubuntu
I have a tech3 348 keyboard for which the backlight does not work in my Linux Ubuntu operating system
I need to learn or start or understand the LEDs on my keyboard and 348 in which it does not turn on even using the terminal with the required functions

Does this answer your question? Keyboard backlight in Ubuntu 22.04
